# Import local JS files into Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, import

I'm having terrible problems when trying to import an external JS project into my meteor folder. This is the project I'll like to use: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#beatles

As you can see, it is necessary to import two scripts. The first one is JQuery, and that was easily solved by adding it with `meteor add jquery`.

The problem came out when I tried to import the second script. I'm not sure how I can use it because, as far as I know, on meteor you cannot just import your script into the head section. For that reason, I've created a new template that is rendered and I put the code in there, but nothing happenend. Later on I've created an event that calls the JS when the image is clicked but without any success.

My question is, Which is the correct way to import a local JS code in meteor as in HTML is done with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jquery-imagemapster is available as an npm package you can do:

```
$ npm install jquery-imagemapster
```

In your project directory and make it available to your project that way.

In early versions of Meteor packages were only available via atmosphere and `$ meteor add`. Later they added npm support and all npm packages became available.

Comment: Thanks, I've done it but I got the same problem when I tried to add it manually. After executing, an error comes out saying: 'Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined' at line 1946 of jquery.imagemapster file

Comment: Seems like an error from the own file. But that's weird because it works perfectly when I run it in HTML. Only does not work when I run it in meteor

Comment: How are you initializing the plug-in? That will be different in Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix npm installs with “meteor” -> “meteor npm install —save ‘js file’. Initializing will be the same as it would be in any other front end environment as will importing it. If you’re having trouble after that, check for it’s existance in your browser console and work from there using its built in properties and methods.